# Yii2 include a controller in view

Tags: php, yii2

I've got a very bad structured proj in Yii2, so if possible please don't pay attention to it.

Here is my proj structure:

[image]

In **results.php** I want to use my **FlightsController** class.
here is my include section from results.php:

```
include \yii\helpers\Url::to('@app/views/site/partials/header.php');
include \yii\helpers\Url::to('@app/controllers/HotelController.php');
include \yii\helpers\Url::to('@app/controllers/ActivitiesController.php');
include \yii\helpers\Url::to('@app/controllers/FlightController.php');
```

FlightController class:

```
class FlightController
{
require_once(\yii\helpers\Url::to('@app/sabre/rest_activities/LeadPriceCalculator.php'));

public static function start_rest_workflow($origin, $destination, $departureDate){
    $workflow = new \Workflow(new \LeadPriceCalendarActivity($origin, $destination, $departureDate));
    $result = $workflow->runWorkflow();

}
}
```

Here I get the error:

```
yii\base\ErrorException Expected array for frame 0
/controllers/FlightController.php    yii\base\ErrorException::__toString
/views/site/results.php yii\web\View::unknown
```

In the first import `require_once(\yii\helpers\Url::to('@app/sabre/rest_activities/LeadPriceCalculator.php'));` .

How Can I correctly import a class from sabre directory from controllers directory?

Comment: dude what are you doing ლ(ಠ益ಠლ)

Answer (score 1):

i think  that you don't know  or not understand  MCV software architecture pattern that it is working in yii2.

I m gona try to explain you  a resum and a few sugerences :)

What is MVC :

- Model: database  and his logic.
- View: html code and show/render the data.
- Controller: big part of logic  of code.

Then  , whe you need a new page in you website , yo need think , is a other part of the same think or it isn't. If it is the same you must set the file in same path that other , like this example .
You have:

- User/form.php
- User/index.php

And you want to add a new page  "view" where it see the data in a list , than the "view" is part of same think (User)  you must set in the same page :

- User/view.php
- User/form.php
- User/index.php

Then , in the controller you must write  a big part of you logic  that one think , in this case User  , and in this Controller  will be 3 actionsthan miniumm   ( because you have 3 view )

**UserController.php**

```
public function actionView($id){
}
public function actionIndex(){
}
public function actionForm(){
}
```

And the last to explain is a models ,  it is simple , this  are a object to represent a tables in you DB and you must be use like that , you can write a querys in this  and call  from controller and make  somethiks.

> In resume , if you will create "result.php"   and you like write clean
>   code you set this file out of path "site" and create other "flight" 
>   by exmaple , and now you can use the code from 
>   **FligthController.php**  en the function inside

```
 public function actionResult(){}
```

Comment: I have already a flightController. But in flight controller I have to call a lot of helper classes that respond for different actions, and as I want structured code, I have to define them in different files and I don't know where it is better to define them